# Any way to control the version of Java Spring STS Gradle plug-in uses?

Tags: eclipse, jetty, gradle

I am using the STS Gradle plugin in Eclipse (Indigo).   I am running on MacOSX.  Eclipse is running Java 1.6, but I have Java 1.7 installed as the default JRE and all my eclipse projects use it without error.

I am trying to get "gradle jettyRun" to work within Eclipse.  It runs perfectly from the command line.   However, when I right click on my web project and say "Run As"->Gradle Build...  then select jettyRun from the dialog box, I get this error message:

```
invalid source release: 1.7
```

Does anyone know if there is anyway to fix this?

[Don't think it matters, but I am running Gradle 1.1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this issue](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2276) suggests, provided you're using above version 3.0.0.M1 of the STS plugin, there should be a Gradle preference page where you can select the JVM installation to use.

Not sure for earlier versions of STS plugin. You can try setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable before launching your Eclipse. Might help.

Comment: Thanks!  Would not have known this so would not have ever checked!  Am running 2.9 something.  Will upgrade today.